# Can I use a 6v dc adaptor for 6v ac?

Tags: ac, dc

I recently bought a vtech cordless phone, only to discover the adaptor is not 110-220 ac to 6v ac. its almost impossible to find a 220v ac 6v ac in my part of the world.

my question is, can I use a 220v ac 6v dc instead?

---

[image]

thank you for all your response.

I did not realize the vtech phone I bought 4 years ago is also ac/ac and I have been using a 220v ac 6v dc for it. Yikes! should I stop using it? no problem so far.

---

Is this youtube video to convert AC-DC Adapter To AC-AC accurate?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnowEUtkUws

thank you

lar

Comment: No, probably not. Take the phone back to the supplier and ask for one compatible wih your AC supply.

Comment: VTech makes real phones? I knew this brand only from the annoying toys my children have, with the same voice on all of them, saying the same things over and over again... Anyway, it seems strange to me that the phone requires 6V *AC* as an input. Are you sure of that?

Comment: Also, ac/ac adapters are simply transformers and should be easy to get. Really.

Comment: @dim I was surprised, too, but: https://www.vtechphones.com/

Comment: I agree with Marcus. Another option would be using a 220Vac/9VDC adaptor instead.

Comment: Your phone didn't come with an adapter?

Comment: So there is no problem substituting the required 6v ac with a 9 v dc?

Comment: Immibis, it came with a 110v adaptor, but I need to use it in a 220v country

Comment: @dim Vtech also makes Shure wireless microphones, Allen&Heath mixers, Soundcraft products and so on. Huge factory with many OE customers.

Comment: It worked with DC? Maybe it's just you erroneously believing that it works with AC. Check this aspect well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the following operation with the help of a professional/someone who knows what she/he is doing:

You can buy a transformer with a ratio of primary turns/secondary turns of 36 or 22 depending on what is your outlet voltage from a local electronics shop.If you take care of the current ,too,it's probably not that hard to create the needed supply.Connect the 110-220V to the socket and the 6V directly to the phone's input.

You need isolation from the mains in order to prevent shock and that's why I suggested the experienced partner.Outlet voltage is **dangerous**.Don't play with it.

Comment: Rectifying and smoothing 6V AC gives more or less about 7 to 7.5 volts DC (load dependent) and not 6 V DC.

Comment: @Andy What you said is a bit farther.I would say it's 6.5V-7V usually.Yet I've seen an output of 2V past the the rated voltage,but that was an AC-AC supply.

Comment: @Andy Can you explain please the judgement behind your statement?As you know,I'm not that experienced and ideas don't come to me as fast as they come for you.

Comment: The peak voltage from a 6V RMS sine wave is 8.485 volts or about 8.5 volts. With a very lightly loaded bridge rectifier the output could be a volt lower at 7.5 volts and, with heavier loading could be 7.0 volts (or maybe lower)

Comment: @Andy aka I see were you're getting.Thanks a bunch for your feedback.